# Is there some way to get 1 result in this SQL for each condition inside WHERE? I'm using TOP 1 WITH TIES but it doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the minor value greater than the *t.TEDATA* input where the *t.TECODSENSOR* is not necessarily different.

For example, is this case I get 2 results because the *t.TECODSENSOR* is different:

```
1           SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
2                   t.TECODSENSOR
3               ,   t.TETEMP
4               ,   t.TEDATA
5           FROM TELEMETRIA t
6           WHERE
7               (t.TECODSENSOR = 2661 AND t.TEDATA >= '2022-01-18 09:50:23.100')
8            OR (t.TECODSENSOR = 28 AND t.TEDATA >= '2021-09-18 22:35:34.413')
9           ORDER By ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by t.TECODSENSOR ORDER by t.TEDATA ASC)
```

The result

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|   t.TECODSENSOR   |  t.TETEMP |      t.TEDATA         |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       2661        |    8.9    |2022-01-18 09:51:55.520|
|        28         |    20.5   |2021-09-18 22:37:34.413|
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

But if the *line 8* is "**OR (t.TECODSENSOR = 2661 AND t.TEDATA >= '2022-01-18 09:43:54.100')**" I only get 1 result, and it is for the *line 8* condition.

The result:

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|   t.TECODSENSOR   |  t.TETEMP |      t.TEDATA         |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       2661        |    8.6    |2022-01-18 09:44:32.413|
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

What I want to:

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|   t.TECODSENSOR   |  t.TETEMP |      t.TEDATA         |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       2661        |    8.9    |2022-01-18 09:51:55.520|
|       2661        |    8.6    |2022-01-18 09:44:32.413|
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

So, I need to get 1 result for each condition inside the **WHERE**.

Comment: You have sql-server and mysql tagged, it can't be both. Please fix your tags. Also, please provide some sample data (not as an image), see: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: I removed the MySql tag since your `top 1` syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: I just Fixed it!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - you're getting what you asked for. Which is "the row with the smallest value for `TEDATA` for each value of `TECODSENSOR`"

Longer version - first, let's re-write your query so that we can inspect how SQL is determining which rows to put into the result set

```sql
with cte as (
    SELECT
           t.TECODSENSOR
       ,   t.TETEMP
       ,   t.TEDATA
       ,   [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by t.TECODSENSOR ORDER by t.TEDATA ASC)
    FROM TELEMETRIA t
    WHERE
       (t.TECODSENSOR = 2661 AND t.TEDATA >= '2022-01-18 09:50:23.100')
    OR (t.TECODSENSOR = 28 AND t.TEDATA >= '2021-09-18 22:35:34.413')
)
SELECT
       t.TECODSENSOR
   ,   t.TETEMP
   ,   t.TEDATA
   ,   [rn]
FROM CTE
WHERE [rn] <= 5;
```

The `[rn] <= 5` is just so we can see how SQL is enumerating the rows; to be fully equivalent to your original query (i.e. `select top(1) with ties`), we'd use `[rn] = 1`;

Now, if we change the predicate in the way that you mentioned in your question so that both predicates identify the same `TECODSENSOR` value, that effectively rewrites your query to (excerpted)

```sql
WHERE t.TECODSENSOR = 2661
   AND (
      t.TEDATA >= '2022-01-18 09:50:23.100'
      OR t.TEDATA >= '2021-09-18 22:35:34.413'
   )
```

which then further simplifies to

```sql
WHERE t.TECODSENSOR = 2661
   AND t.TEDATA >= '2021-09-18 22:35:34.413'
```

All of that is to explain why you're seeing what you're seeing. If you do want to get one row per compound predicate (that is, tuples of `TECODSENSOR`, `TEDATA`) that you're providing) regardless of duplicates in the `TECODSENSOR` value across tuples, I think you'll have to query each tuple separately. You can probably do some tricks with `UNION ALL` if you don't want to issue N queries and consume N results. But it gets weird fast (imo).